# How can I exclude certain words from a matched search with regular expressions?

Tags: regex, search

I'm using TinyTinyRSS and want to organize my articles with the implemented filter feature that supports regular expressions. Normally, I filter for words like `star` and everything that contains `star` is found. But I also want to exclude certain words like `started, starshine` or `seastar`.

F.i, my Google query would look like this: `star -started|starshine|seastar`

So what's the appropriate command in RegExp?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google for "complement of a regular expression", there you will find that this is not that obvious, there is an regular expression for your problem but it might turn out to be very funny looking.

Comment: I've searched before, but didn't find a way, even an "ugly" one.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of word boundaries:

```
\bstar\b
```

Will look for the word 'star' and nothing else, meaning nothing like `custard` or `stars`.

If you want to avoid matching only those and if you are using a regex engine which supports lookarounds fully, you can perhaps use:

```
(?<!sea)star(?!ted|shine)
```

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP actually wants. He need to find all words containing `star`, just not certain words.

Comment: @sojusnik But how does the second regex work for you? It will definitely get longer the more exclusions there are, but this one will match `star`, unless it is in the words you mentioned.

Comment: @sojusnik Any luck with the regex?

Comment: I wasn't able to test this command for lack of time and will reply when finding some free time. Please bear with me.